# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline also indexes branches from PR

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Currently I have configured in the Jenkins multibranch pipeline so that `dev`, `stage`, `uat` and `prod` branches get indexed. When I'm creating PRs from any feature branch to the `dev` branch, only `dev` branch gets indexed which is correct, but when I do a PR from `dev` to `stage`, for example, both the `stage` and `dev` branches are getting indexed which shouldn't happen, only the target branch `stage` should get indexed, without source branch `dev`.

My current configuration looks like this:

[image: Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Configuration]

What should I change so that always only the target branch to which PR is merged to is going to get indexed? In my example, only `stage` branch, when the PR is coming from `dev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more testing I have noticed that the `dev` branch gets crossed out when a PR is created to the `stage` branch and after approval of PR and merge the `dev` branch is not crossed out anymore. This action is detected in Jenkins as if the branch is newly added and there for it indexes the branch again.

The solution was to set the `Discover branches` Behaviour to `All branches`. That prevented 'excluding' the `dev` branch from discovery and therefore the branch doesn't get indexed again after the PR merge.